# How can I stop VS Code Intellisense from automatically appearing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm not working in JavaScript, Intellisense is unfortunately not often terribly helpful.  How can I make it only appear when I hit <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, and not just appear automatically?

I don't want to turn it off completely.  I just want it to only appear when I explicitly ask it to.

Answer (score 0):

Although [the VS Code Intellisense documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) does not define "Quick Suggestions", apparently *"quick suggestions" **is** Intellisense*—or is the visible face of it. (Are there also slow suggestions?  I have no idea.  The name seems to suggest being just one aspect of Intellisense, but... it turns out that it seems to be pretty much the central thing.)

So to stop Intellisense from appearing uninvited, you have to turn off "quick suggestions".  Here's how I did that, in my user settings:

```
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  },
```